# Wordpress redirect and htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have to rewrite this url `http://www.domainurl.com/title_of_the_article_postID.html`
to `http://www.domainurl.com/?p=postID`

The problem it's that I have some other articles with this kind of url `http://www.domainurl.com/gg/mm/yyyy/title_of_the_article_postID.html`
and I want to keep them same.

The postID's are numerical. For example,

- `/title_of_the_article_21.html`
- `/title_of_the_article_347.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using: **RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+)_([0-9]+).html$ /?p=$2**